# Sending CGFloat and String Values with GKMatch.sendData(toAllPlayers: , with: .reliable)

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

I am making a real time multiplayer game with Game Center but have run into a road block. All I need to be able to do for this gamer to function is to send CGFloat and String values between the devices. I am trying to accomplish this by using the `GKMatch.sendData(toAllPlayers: , with: .reliable)` method and the `GKMathc.didreceiveData` Method. However When I try to send the data, see the code below:

```
        let sending = number
        let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: sending.littleEndian) { Data($0) }
        
        do {
            try Match.sendData(toAllPlayers: data, with: .reliable)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

It always prints the error. The specific error states: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)`  if knowing it helps.

If anyone could show me how to convert numbers and strings into data and back again that'd be much appreciated, all of my research thus far has been a dead end!

Comment: You have not told us what `number` is.

Comment: "If anyone could show me how to convert numbers and strings into data and back again that'd be much appreciated"  Have you run a search and helped yourself?

Comment: Sorry about that Matt, I must have mis copied the function, 'number' is simply a CGFloat input that I give to the function. So number is simply any CGFloat

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, all of the searching I have done so far has returned very little useful information, most of the Int to data methods I have found have simply not worked. Being new to GameKit, and sending data in swift, after around a day of searching I believed it was reasonable to turn to forum based help. Sorry I did not make that clearer in the post El Tomato, :)

Comment: Well, what you're doing is not how to convert a CGFloat into a stream of Data bytes. So is that what the question is?